# VSIX in VS2022 - Get current theme

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

I am developing an extension for Visual Studio, and I need to detect what theme the user has in his VS user settings.

How can I achieve this?

I am using following code to try and get the theme:

```
            var shellSettingsManager = new ShellSettingsManager(ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider);
            var store = shellSettingsManager.GetReadOnlySettingsStore(SettingsScope.UserSettings);
            var theme = store.GetString("General", "CurrentTheme", string.Empty);
```

But when debugging, theme is always empty:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you get it from Theme > BackupThemeId
Mine returns `{1ded0138-47ce-435e-84ef-9ec1f439b749}`, which is the GUID for the `Dark` theme.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/vsix-color-compiler?view=vs-2022

```
var shellSettingsManager = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Settings.ShellSettingsManager(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider);
var store = shellSettingsManager.GetReadOnlySettingsStore(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.SettingsScope.UserSettings);
var theme = store.GetString("Theme", "BackupThemeId", string.Empty);
```